# Nginx: Wordpress blog at non root context

Tags: java, php, wordpress, nginx

I've a site that runs in java and also have a wordpress blog(eg. www.example.com & blog.example.com). I want to move blog to /blog context under my site so the url will look like www.example.com/blog.

Since its a wordpress blog, I'm trying to use Ngix at port 80. I've moved java application at 8080 port and using reverse proxy to server java application at root context.

```
server {
    listen: 80;
    server_name: www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://internal-example-host:8080/; #resolved to localhost through /etc/hosts
    }

    location /blog {
        root /path/to/blog/root/folder;
        index index.php index.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-blog.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        }
    }
}
```

To serve blog at /blog, I'm trying to configure location block under nginx server config by setting its own root directory. My java site works correctly. However for blog only homepage works and rest all pages gives 404 error. Logs shows that wordpress/nginx tries to server index.php for every request except home page and static resource.

Can anybody help me out here?

Thanks,
Kiran.

Comment: open your wordpress admin go to permalink setting change permalink to default and save and then  check

Comment: You are missing a `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;` statement to pass pretty permalinks to the WordPress controller.

Comment: Have you changed WP's URL? It might be that WP expects to see /post-name/, but sees /blog/post-name/ instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying. No luck adding /blog in try_files. WP URL correctly points to /blog. @Balwant, I tried to updating permalink to default(plain ?p=1234), it works. But my current site has "Month and name" and can't change that.

Comment: @RichardSmith, thanks for your help. It turns out to be try_files. I placed at wrong location(location ~ \.php$ {) and should be under  location /blog.